# I want to be able to delete a questions/answers(choices) and the subject Codeigniter Delete records from a database

Tags: php, codeigniter

[Database:multi_login, Table:quiz Fields: quizID, question, choice1, choice2, choice3, answer, subject]

My quiz works perfectly, I just want to be able to delete the quiz (which would be done outside of the entering the quiz php page) when in the quiz page, be able to delete answers (choice1, choice2, choice3 or answer) and questions (question).

Model:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class quizmodel extends CI_Model {

    public function getQuestions()
    {
        $this->db->select("quizID, question, choice1, choice2, choice3, answer, subject");
        $this->db->from("quiz");
        $this->db->where("subject",'computing');


        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query->result();

        $num_data_returned = $query->num_rows;

        if ($num_data_returned < 1) {
          echo "There is no data in the database";
          exit();   
        }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Questions extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function quizdisplay()
    {

        $this->load->model('quizmodel');
        $this->data['questions'] = $this->quizmodel->getQuestions();
        $this->load->view('play_quiz', $this->data);

    }

        public function resultdisplay()
    {
        $this->data['checks'] = array(
             'ques1' => $this->input->post('quizid1'),
             'ques2' => $this->input->post('quizid2'),
             'ques3' => $this->input->post('quizid3'),
             'ques4' => $this->input->post('quizid4'),
             'ques5' => $this->input->post('quizid5'),
             'ques6' => $this->input->post('quizid6'),
             'ques7' => $this->input->post('quizid7'),
             'ques8' => $this->input->post('quizid8'),
             'ques9' => $this->input->post('quizid9'),
             'ques10' => $this->input->post('quizid10'),
        );

        $this->load->model('quizmodel');
        $this->data['results'] = $this->quizmodel->getQuestions();
        $this->load->view('result_display', $this->data);
    }
}
```

View for playing Quiz:

```
    <div id="container">
    <h1>Play the Computing Quiz!</h1>

    <form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/Questions/resultdisplay">


    <?php foreach($questions as $row) { ?>

    <?php $ans_array = array($row->choice1, $row->choice2, $row->choice3, $row->answer);
    shuffle($ans_array); ?>

    <p><?=$row->question?></p>

    <input type="radio" name="quizid<?=$row->quizID?>" value="<?=$ans_array[0]?>" required> <?=$ans_array[0]?><br>
    <input type="radio" name="quizid<?=$row->quizID?>" value="<?=$ans_array[1]?>"> <?=$ans_array[1]?><br>
    <input type="radio" name="quizid<?=$row->quizID?>" value="<?=$ans_array[2]?>"> <?=$ans_array[2]?><br>
    <input type="radio" name="quizid<?=$row->quizID?>" value="<?=$ans_array[3]?>"> <?=$ans_array[3]?><br>

    <?php } ?>

    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit!">

    </form>

</div><div id="container">
    <h1>Play the Computing Quiz!</h1>

    <form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/Questions/resultdisplay">


    <?php foreach($questions as $row) { ?>

    <?php $ans_array = array($row->choice1, $row->choice2, $row->choice3, $row->answer);
    shuffle($ans_array); ?>

    <p><?=$row->question?></p>

    <input type="radio" name="quizid<?=$row->quizID?>" value="<?=$ans_array[0]?>" required> <?=$ans_array[0]?><br>
    <input type="radio" name="quizid<?=$row->quizID?>" value="<?=$ans_array[1]?>"> <?=$ans_array[1]?><br>
    <input type="radio" name="quizid<?=$row->quizID?>" value="<?=$ans_array[2]?>"> <?=$ans_array[2]?><br>
    <input type="radio" name="quizid<?=$row->quizID?>" value="<?=$ans_array[3]?>"> <?=$ans_array[3]?><br>

    <?php } ?>

    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit!">

    </form>

</div>
```

PLEASE HELP!

Answer (score 0):

In your model:

```
function deleteQuiz($quiz_id)
{
   $this->load->database();
   $this->db->where('QuizID',$quiz_id);
   $this->db->delete('multi_login.quiz');
}
```

If you want to delete a quiz, from your controller just call

```
$this->quizmodel->deleteQuiz($quiz_id);
```

and the whole quiz (all its questions) will be gone

Answer (score 0):

try this. i hope it will help you.

create a delete function in your controller and call that function on button click if you want.

```
function deleteQuiz($id){
$this->model_name->delete_quiz_by_id($id);
}
```

/model

```
function delete_quiz($id){
return $this->db->where('quiz_id',$id)->delete('table_name');
}
```